# Определение оси цилиндра по координатам точек на его поверхности

Tags: c#, 3d, java, c++, геометрия

Есть прибор который определяет координаты точек на поверхности цилиндра, и выдает массив этих координат(X,Y,Z) в абсолютных величинах. Как можно имея значения этих точек определить ось цилиндра(то есть координаты прямой). У меня в голове пока геометрический метод. То есть программно (на базе некоего 3D движка) составить поверхность, далее опираясь на нее объемную модель цилиндра и там уже определить ее ось. Вопрос как?

[image]

Comment: Так простая же геометрия? У Вас есть радиус цилиндра? Отбрасываете координату оси цилиндра, потом "проводите круг через точку" и находите центр. Хотя, если у Вас координаты относительно центра цилиндра - то ось всегда будет (0,0,Z) ?

Comment: @Чад координаты как раз таки относительно измерительного прибора, и при этом они расположены на поверхности цилиндра только с одной стороны и описывают часть окружности которая не факт(я не знаю), а скорее всего та плоскость в которой она расположена не перпендикулярна оси цилиндра. Мысль такая ято по этим точкам построить поверхность, а ее в свою очередь преобразовать в цилиндр, а как пока не вьезжаю!

Comment: 1. Вам надо нормализовать координаты чтобы ось цилиндра была перпендикулярно плоскости XY

2. После этого отбрасываете Z, загоняете точки в уравнение круга ( (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2 = R^2 ) из чего находите a и b

3. Делаете обратное преобразование относительно пункта 1 для (a,b,0)-(a,b,1)

Comment: Как я нормализую ось относительно плоскости XY? Это труба длиной 20 метров и диаметром метра 2-3?

Comment: SpatialAnalyzer v itoi programme mozno vichislit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле, всё не так сложно.

Во-первых, цилиндр есть поверхность второго порядка. Очевидно? Значит, он задаётся уравнением вида

```
a_11 x^2 + a_12 xy + a_13 xz + ... + a_33 z^2 + a_0 = 0
```

Подставляя имеющиеся точки, получаете систему линейных уравнений на коэффициенты `a_i`. Заметьте, что коэффициенты определены с точностью до постоянного множителя, поэтому система будет иметь серию решений, вам подходит любое ненулевое.

Первая часть есть. Теперь, вам нужно найти ось, исходя из уравнения. Для этого можно воспользоваться классификацией поверхностей второго порядка (например, [здесь](http://mathhelpplanet.com/static.php?p=klassifikatsiya-poverhnostyey-po-invariantam)), это уже чисто математическая задача.

---

P.S.: если ваша система координат ориентирована по отношению к трубе известным образом, то конечно задача сильно упрощается.

Comment: В том то и дело что это реальный измерительный инструмент и он расположен может быть как угодно, вследствие чего возникает сложность с определением оси. Уравнение поверхности второго порядка для элиптического цилиндра верно в том случае когда начало координат расположено на оси OZ.

Comment: @vanyamelikov: почему же? Уравнение второго порядка будет в любой системе координат, просто для оси, совпадающей с Oz, оно будет иметь простой вид `x^2 + y^2 = R^2`.

Comment: Да дошло a_0 это учтет, но у меня не получается постановка задачи! То есть систему уравнений не могу написать нормально зная x,y,z координаты 10 точек относительно статичного(точка отсчета) измерительного инструмента.

Comment: @vanyamelikov: Не только `a_0`, а и все остальные коэффициенты. А почему не можете написать систему? У вас есть 10 точек `(x_i, y_i, z_i)`, вы пишете:

    a_11 x_1^2 + a_12 x_1 y_1 + a_13 x_1 z_1 + a_22 y_1^2 + a_23 y_1 z_1 + a_33 z_1^2 + a_0 = 0
    a_11 x_2^2 + a_12 x_2 y_2 + a_13 x_2 z_2 + a_22 y_2^2 + a_23 y_2 z_2 + a_33 z_2^2 + a_0 = 0
    a_11 x_3^2 + a_12 x_3 y_3 + a_13 x_3 z_3 + a_22 y_3^2 + a_23 y_3 z_3 + a_33 z_3^2 + a_0 = 0
    ...

`x_i`, `y_i`, `z_i` у вас есть, неизвестные все `a_i`.

Comment: @VladD спасибо но это мне в школе рассказывали) Смотрите проблема у меня в том чтобы имея эти значения программно построить поверхность цилиндра и по ней определить уравнение прямой, которая является осью цилиндра. Какой метод для этого использовать? Как определить отклонение от идеального случая? Как я понимаю для наиболее точного решения данного уравнения необходимо 7 координат, так как это в простейшем случае удовлетворяет решению линейной системы уравнений с 7 неизвестными.

Comment: @vanyamelikov: О, так у вас крутая школа, раз вы классификацию поверхностей второго порядка проходили. Ну, а вы читали текст по ссылке? (Или свой же школьный конспект.) Там есть пункт «Определение канонического базиса для поверхности 2-го порядка». Берёте канонический базис, его ось Oz и есть ось цилиндра.

Comment: @VladD я имел ввиду, что в школьной программе дают материал по составлению линейных уравнений. А что касается моего вопроса, то вы его сводите опять же чисто к математике, а я задаю вопрос на форуме программистов с целью выяснения наличия готовых методов для решения данной задачи. Вот например среды инженерного 3D моделирования позволяют определять все параметры объемной фигуры, значит используя некоторый функционал такого движка можно решить подобную задачу.

Comment: @vanyamelikov: Ну да, а ваш вопрос и есть чисто математический. Если вы хотите не сами считать, а чтобы за вас посчитала чужая библиотека, тогда ждите следующего ответа.